# Google Map Image not loading on PDF

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, symfony

I am working on functionality which is converting html to PDF in Symfony2. Everything written in html like images/texts are displaying on newly genrated PDF but the google map is not displaying on PDF.
I am plotting map from below script.

```
function initializeMap( ) {
var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 17,
        center:  new google.maps.LatLng(propLatLng.lat(), propLatLng.lng()),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
googleMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: propLatLng,
    map: googleMap,
    title: propAddress
}); }
```

Having below div into my html.

```
<div id="map_canvas"  style="width:900px;height:700px;"></div>
```

Map is loading into the html But not displaying on PDF. Its showing empty space. Please HELP.

Comment: how do you generate the PDF? Bundle/etc...

Comment: I am using snappy like $pdf =$this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($pdfHtml);

Comment: Are you enabled js support? try rendering as follow: `$pdf =$this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($pdfHtml, array('enable-javascript' => true));`

Comment: Maybe you can use a workaround by replacing your dynamic google map by a google map static image like: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/. However @Matteo's suggestion would be better if it works.

Comment: Matteo: Having same issue after adding enable-javascript as true.  nomayann: I will try your solution.

Comment: see https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle/issues/55 for further details

Comment: Got the google map image on PDF after replacing dynamic google map static image. I will post solution on same link. Thanks Guys!!

Answer (score 0):

I can able to displayed google map with marker on PDF as:

```
<div class="print-show">
<img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=yourLatitude,yourLongitude&zoom=16&scale=false&size=900x600&maptype=roadmap&format=png&visual_refresh=true&markers=size:mid|color:red|label:|yourLatitude,yourLongitude"/>
</div>
```

EDIT : Static Maps images can be returned in any size up to 640 x 640 pixels.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/intro

Comment: how do i show multiple points on map in pdf??? please help me thank you in advance.